# conent hash value is disapear and not calculated after edit blobs properties in azure blob storage

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-blob-storage

I'm trying to edit blob's Cache-control value using azure powershell
but content-hash value is disapear after 'setProperties()'...
in ms doc, "content hash (md5) will be calculated automatically when it updated"
but in my case, not calculated and just disapear...

how to edit blob's properties without missing properties in azure powershell?
i want just setting cache-control

(here is my code)

```
#get target blob from azure blob storage container
$blob = Get-AzStorageBlob -Container $containerName -Blob "gigachad2.jpg" -Context $context

#get content type from blob
$contentType = $blob.BlobClient.GetProperties().Value.ContentType

#set cache control value
$blob.ICloudBlob.Properties.CacheControl = "max-age=3500"

#set original content type value
$blob.ICloudBlob.Properties.ContentType = $contentType

#update blob's properties
$blob.ICloudBlob.SetProperties()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is expected behavior. When you set system properties like cache-control on a blob and do not include other properties in `setProperties` call, they will be removed.

From the REST API documentation [`link`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/set-blob-properties?tabs=azure-ad#remarks):

[image]

To fix this issue, you would need to get the blob properties first and make changes to the values fetched. Once you have changed the properties you want to change, call set properties with changed properties.

**UPDATE**

Please try the following code:

```
#get target blob from azure blob storage container
$blob = Get-AzStorageBlob -Container $containerName -Blob "gigachad2.jpg" -Context $context

$blob.ICloudBlob.FetchAttributes()

$blob.ICloudBlob.Properties.ContentType = $contentType
$blob.ICloudBlob.Properties.CacheControl = "max-age=3500"
$blob.ICloudBlob.SetProperties()
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. but content-hash value is readonly.
but other properties can copy and set on value.
i using this command 
$blob.ICloudBlob.Properties.CacheControl = "max-age=123"
$blob.ICloudBlob.SetProperties()

Comment: Please edit your question and include your complete code.

Comment: sure, i adding picture of powershell on my question.

Comment: Please…No pictures. Post the actual code and complete one.

Comment: i'm sorry..I have edited my question.

Comment: Updated my answer with sample code. HTH.